# How to achieve High Availability , Fail Over and Replication in AWS RDS in same setup?

Tags: amazon-rds

I want to create AWS RDS (MYSQL) setup , which can give me high Availability, Fail Over and Replication. I have tried AWS multi-AZ but it will not provide Read Replica. So can any one please help me out in creating topology through which i can achieve  high Availability, Fail Over and Replication.

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried to do it? Did you have any particular problems? See: [High Availability (Multi-AZ) for Amazon RDS - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html)

Comment: I have tried Multi-AZ but read replica is not achieved using this. For same i have edited the question. Thanks :)

Comment: [Working with Read Replicas - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html)